# Regarding Hadoop Web interface

Tags: hadoop

Is there any web interface for Hadoop to submit the hadoop jobs and monitor their status, and to download the output? ( other than The normal web ui's coming with apache hadoop ( dfshealth.jsp and jobtracker.jsp).

Is there any web ui to explore HDFS and todo all other operations( create,delete,download etc)

Thanks
MRK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check to see this project: [Hue](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2010/07/whats-new-in-cdh3b2-hue/)

Code can be downloaded from [github Hue](https://github.com/cloudera/hue).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Seems HUE works with CDH only. Is it works with Standard Apache Hadoop. IS CDH supports solaris operating system?

Comment: Yes, seems HUE needs Hadoop from CDH3 Beta 4 or later, [here](http://cloudera.github.com/hue/docs-1.2.0/manual.html#_hue_installation_instructions), but CDH version hadoop can work with any os that hadoop can, I even made it work on my mac osx.